# Unable to make PHPStorm work with Node.js and Docker

Tags: docker, node.js, phpstorm

Here is my setup:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is some of the errors I am getting:

[image]

So it seems I have two issues.

1. Something wrong with the networking.
2. For some reason it doesn't load my project into the container.

I am out of ideas to make this work.

What am I missing?